# Downloading file before is ready

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, web

I have a button to download a file from a db and writing info on it, but the button download the file before write the info so when I open it it's empty...

I have something like this:

```
/*taking blob from database and saved on a folder*/

File f = new File("file name");
for (int i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++) {
    /*write on the file*/
}


response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", f.getName()));
```

any ideas?

Comment: I don't think your problem is timing; are you sure that an attachment like that is the correct way to send a file from the server? Why don't you try to create the file yourself to see if timing is your problem? If it is, try to close and/or flush everything you used to write (the part you omited).

Comment: You are not closing the file handler.

Comment: I'm using InputStreamReader and CSVWriter, i'm closing them just before the "for"

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov you were right, can you add it as an answer?

Comment: I can skip that, thanks for the gesture, but as long as your code runs that's my real upvote ^_^

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov You're gonna make me cry hahaha, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't closing the file handler